# How to avoid Thread Interrupted Exception

Tags: java, multithreading, glassfish

I'm indexing pdf files using Apache lucene with threads. Some threads take time more than 15 minutes. After 15 minutes of thread execution it will throw Thread interrupted Exception.Is there a way to increase the time limit to avoid this issue.

I got this exception when there is a single thread running and it indexed nearly 76% of its pdf files.
application server is Glassfish

---

```
    List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<Thread>();
    Thread worker;
    for (int a = 1;a <= count; a++) {

        IndexManualRunnable indexManualRunnable =
                new IndexManualRunnable(indexfileLocation, collections, manual, processId);
        worker = new Thread(indexManualRunnable);

        worker.setName(manual.getName());
        worker.setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);
        worker.start();

        threads.add(worker);
    }

        for (Thread thread : threads) {
            try {
                thread.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException interruptedException) {

                saveReport("", "", "Interrupted Exception", 1, processId, Category.INDEXING, thread.getName());
                interruptedException.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hard to see why this is a problem, unless you catch it somewhere and handle it wrongly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

I see that you are using Glassfish and are saying this interrupt is occurring every time at 15 minutes. It appears Glassfish is set to timeout at around 900 seconds which is 15 minutes by default - this throws an InterruptException.

Since your application viably needs to process for longer than 15 minutes, update the following server config to a time limit you see fit.

```
http.request-timeout-seconds
```

Here is an example asadmin command to update the property but I have not tested it:

```
 # asadmin set server-config.network-config.protocols.protocol.<listener-name>.http.request-timeout-seconds=-1

- NOTE: <listener-name> is the name of the listener they wish to disable the  timeout on.

 - (-1) means unlimited
```

To deal with an interrupted thread you can catch and handle the exception yourself. If you want the thread to continue executing regardless you would theoretically do nothing - but to keep the code clean and proper I would implement it as below:

```
boolean interrupted = false;
try {
    while (true) {
        try {
            return queue.take();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            interrupted = true;
            // fall through and retry
        }
    }
} finally {
    if (interrupted)
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}
```

I like this example because it does not just leave an empty catch clause, it instead preserves the fact that it was called in a boolean. It does this so that when it finally does complete you can check if it was interrupted and if so respect it and interrupt the current thread.

For more information and where the example came from look into the following article:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp05236/

Comment: I got interrupted exception after 15 minutes of thread execution. What do I need is to increase the time limit more than 15 minutes.

Comment: @chamikaWKK Why? What are you doing when you catch it?

Comment: Not sure why you would want to prevent the thread from being interrupted altogether if you implement the catch clause I mentioned in my answer, but to prevent interruptions from happening as often I have updated my answer with information regarding thread priority.

Comment: Why will a high priority reduce interruptions?

Comment: It won't guarantee the reduction of interruptions but the scheduler will try to allocate more resources to a thread with higher priority and if the other threads are low priority it may gain more resources and "reduce" interruptions as it will be given priority. However, it is not guaranteed and makes your application dependent on how the OS's task scheduler works. This is why I suggested the method above.

Comment: So in other words by occupying less elapsed time it will score fewer of these 15-minute interrupts over its life?

Comment: I have redacted the information regarding Thread Priority as it really is just a sad attempt at reducing interruptions. I have updated my answer with regards to Glassfish and it may be what the OP was looking for.

Comment: I have change the domain.xml in glassfhis <thread-pools>
        <thread-pool name="http-thread-pool" idle-thread-timeout-seconds="1800" />
        <thread-pool max-thread-pool-size="200" name="thread-pool-1" idle-thread-timeout-seconds="1800" />
      </thread-pools>

Answer (score 0):

Change the domain.xml in Glassfish

```
      <thread-pools>
        <thread-pool name="http-thread-pool" idle-thread-timeout-seconds="1800" />
        <thread-pool max-thread-pool-size="200" name="thread-pool-1" idle-thread-timeout-seconds="1800" />
      </thread-pools>
```

increase the idle-thread-timeout-seconds