# Hibernate and InterruptedException

Tags: java, hibernate, vaadin, c3p0

I have a vaadin application which uses hibernate and uploaded in glassfish, and we're getting this error:

```
AdmissionWeb:2018-07-03 12:01:06 [WARN ][http-listener-2(15)]com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@1c40470 -- an attempt to checkout a resource was interrupted, and the pool is still live: some other thread must have either interrupted the Thread attempting checkout!
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1414)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:606)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:526)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutAndMarkConnectionInUse(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:755)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:682)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider.getConnection(C3P0ConnectionProvider.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:292)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:157)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doBegin(JdbcTransaction.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1432)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2260.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:352)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy648.beginTransaction(Unknown Source)
    at no.solarsoft.venus2.admissionweb2.DatabaseUtil.getSession(DatabaseUtil.java:52)
    at no.solarsoft.venus2.admissionweb2.model.DataManager.getAdmission(DataManager.java:845)
    at no.solarsoft.venus2.admissionweb2.AdmissionWebUI.init(AdmissionWebUI.java:178)
    at com.vaadin.ui.UI.doInit(UI.java:675)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UIInitHandler.getBrowserDetailsUI(UIInitHandler.java:214)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UIInitHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UIInitHandler.java:74)
    at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:41)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1408)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:364)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.servlet.TyrusServletFilter.doFilter(TyrusServletFilter.java:253)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)]]
```

I don't know why this happens. Everything seemed to be normal.

Here's the hibernate.cfg.xml :

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>    
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>        
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period"> 120</property> <!-- In seconds -->
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>         
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">3600</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">100</property>
        <property name="c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property>
```

We have a recursive method handlePayment() which calls itself every 10 seconds until we post a callback, the payment fails, or it times out (the timeout is set to 60 minutes.

```
private PxPaymentResponseData handlePayment(String paymentId, long timeoutTimestamp, boolean shouldPostCallback, String admissionId) throws Exception {
    List<String> nodesToExpand = Arrays.asList("urls", "transactions", "payeeInfo", "prices");
    PayExAccountV2 pxAccount = PayExUtil.findPayExAccountForAdmission(admissionId);
    PxPaymentResponse pxPayment = PxPaymentService.getPayment(paymentId, nodesToExpand, pxAccount.getToken());
    Optional<PxTransactionData> lastTx = PxPaymentUtil
            .findLastTransaction(pxPayment.getPaymentData().getTransactions().getTransactionList());

    if (lastTx.isPresent()) {
        PxTransactionData txData = lastTx.get();
        String state = txData.getState();

        if (PxTransaction.State.COMPLETED.value().equalsIgnoreCase(state)) {
            if (PxTransaction.Type.CAPTURE.value().equalsIgnoreCase(txData.getType())) {
                return pxPayment.getPaymentData();
            } else if (PxTransaction.Type.AUTHORIZATION.value().equalsIgnoreCase(txData.getType())) {
                if (shouldPostCallback) {
                    CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> issuePayExCallback(pxPayment.getPaymentData(), txData, admissionId));
                }
                wait(pxPayment.getPaymentData().getId(), PAYEX_REQUEST_DELAY, timeoutTimestamp);
                return handlePayment(paymentId, timeoutTimestamp, false, admissionId);
            }
        } else if (PxTransaction.State.INITIALIZED.value().equalsIgnoreCase(state)) {
            wait(pxPayment.getPaymentData().getId(), PAYEX_REQUEST_DELAY, timeoutTimestamp);
            return handlePayment(paymentId, timeoutTimestamp, false, admissionId);
        } else if (PxTransaction.State.FAILED.value().equalsIgnoreCase(state)) {
            if (PxTransaction.Type.AUTHORIZATION.value().equalsIgnoreCase(txData.getType())
                    || PxTransaction.Type.CAPTURE.value().equalsIgnoreCase(txData.getType())) {
                handleFailedPayment(pxPayment.getPaymentData(), txData);
            }
        }
    } else {
        log.warn("Could not find any transactions for payment: " + paymentId);
    }
    throw new Exception("Payment not handled!");
}
```

the wait() method calls Thread.sleep().

```
private void wait(String paymentId, final int seconds, long timeoutTimestamp)
        throws Exception {
    if (isTimeoutElapsed(timeoutTimestamp)) {
        throw new PaymentTimeoutException("Payment processing session has timed out for payment " + paymentId);
    }

    try {
        Thread.sleep(seconds * 1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I don't know if the error has something to do with the wait() method.  I hope someone can help me. We have increased the max pool size in glassfish to 200, but it didn't help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your Glassfish configuration is set to interrupt Threads quicker than your defined sleep time.

See this one for more details: [How to avoid Thread Interrupted Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29069877/how-to-avoid-thread-interrupted-exception)

Comment: I have one more question. Was it normal that the application didn't work at all after that error?

Comment: It didn't help btw. I still get the same exception :(